# my destroy? and upvote? methods not working with Pundit even though I have authorised them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I have just installed Pundit on my app. I have managed to implement pundit for the  new create and show methods however when it comes to my destroy and up vote methods I get the following error `` Pundit::NotDefinedError in HairstylesController#upvote unable to find policy `NilClassPolicy` for `nil ``

here is my repo for ease of understanding if needed: https://github.com/Angela-Inniss/hair-do

I have authorized the two methods, 'upvote' and 'destroy' in my controller. I have updated the relevant policy. Please see code below.

Controller with methods in question:

```
  def destroy
    authorize @hairstyle
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:id])
    @hairstyle.destroy
    redirect_to hairstyles_path
  end

  def upvote
    authorize @hairstyle
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:id])
    @hairstyle.upvote_from current_user
    redirect_to hairstyles_path
  end
```

pundit policy.rb file:

```
  def upvote?
    record.user == user
    # - record: the restaurant passed to the `authorize` method in controller
    # - user:   the `current_user` signed in with Devise.
  end

  def destroy?
    record.user == user
  end
```

index.html.erb file destroy html

```
 <% if policy(hairstyle).destroy? %>
              <p><%= link_to "Delete", hairstyle_path(hairstyle),method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%></p>
           <% end %>
```

index.html.erb file upvote html (which worked before i added pundit )

```
   <%= link_to like_hairstyle_path(hairstyle), method: :put do %>
               <i class="fa fa-heart">
                <span><%= hairstyle.get_upvotes.size %><span>
               </i>
            <% end %>
```

I would like the user to be able to upvote on a hairstyle
I would like the user to be able to delete their hairstlye.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you call `authorize` after that the object is set? Try to move from

```
authorize @hairstyle
@hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:id])
```

to

```
@hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:id])
authorize @hairstyle
```

Comment: I was just about to say that. The hairstyle is nil, and it uses the class of the thing you’re trying to authorize, for the policy class (HairstylePolicy, NilClassPolicy).

Comment: I tried what you said for the delete method and it worked however for the upvote method I changed authorization to AFTER the object was set  then clicked the upvote on my site I get this error ``Pundit::NotAuthorizedError in HairstylesController#upvote not allowed to upvote? this... #<`` It's strange because as you can see I have authorized the method :S Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I resolved my issue.
Part of the reason was, as you both said above that I was calling the authorize in the wrong place it should have been after the object was set.

Next the reason why I got the error:

`Pundit::NotAuthorizedError in HairstylesController#upvote not allowed to upvote? this... #<` was because instead of putting:

`def upvote?
  record.user == user
end`

in my policy for the upvote? method,

I should have put this:

`def upvote?
   return true
 end`